# PHP auto-add to $_FILES array

Tags: php, jquery

I am updating the image uploader for my CMS; loading images with matching thumbnails. The current setup has paired type='file' inputs loading: someImage.jpg + tn_someImage.jpg. I considered using HTML5:

```
<input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
```

but this probably still presents browser support issues - and incomplete pairs.
I would like to be able to just select the main image and auto-upload thumbs alongside these. I am using:

```
$(document).on('change','#filesUp',function() { // // numbered select input
for (i=1; i<=parseInt($('#filesUp').val()); i++) {
$('#filesToUpload').append('<input class="uploadDir" type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" /><P>'); } });
// then
$(document).on('change','.uploadDir',function() { 
var fileName = 'tn_'+$(this).val(); // thumb naming
 });
```

This gives the name of the selected file thumb pair but... how best to use this? I am working on inserting it into a parallel type="file" input - which I would style='display:hidden'. As best I can see $_FILE does not support value='*' so I am working on slotting it into the 'filesToUpload' naming array. The main question is "is this the best approach?" Debugging array experiments bugs me a tad and proceeding on false assumptions is time wasting. Second question: "is there another way?" I tried getting the local path (assuming thumbs in the same dir) but security disallows.
Once the thumbs are in inputs it then seems easy enough to test the array to see if they actually exist - auto creating them if they don't.

I am unsure how best to approach this and any suggested direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use the same file to generate original and thumb on the backend?

Comment: I prefer custom thumbs - better subject, focus, size... The hope is that admin will crop/size a thumb for each image. I am just looking for a way to cover inevitable gaps.

Comment: Then I suggest you use the JavaScript FormData object.. explanations and examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @Prasun: nice - but, still needs the file path. From your link: oReq.open("POST", "**stash.php**", true); or: data.append("myfile", myBlob, "**filename.txt**"); My hope with $_FILES was that I could incite a tmp file (if my tn_someImage.jpg was present) - or throw an error if it wasn't. I get the feeling that this could be one of those "nice idea - but no banana" scenarios and I will end up just tidying my original layout. But... still looking.